# ¿Acceder a un metodo de una subclase desde un arraylist?

Tags: java, netbeans

estoy haciendo un programa bastante simple para aprender algunas cosas de java y tengo la siguiente super clase:

```
  public abstract class Persona {
    //Atributos
    protected String nombre;
    protected String apellido;
    protected int edad;

    //Metodos
    public Persona(String nombre, String apellido, int edad) {
       this.nombre = nombre;
       this.apellido = apellido;
       this.edad = edad;
    }

    public abstract void viajeDeEquipo();
    public abstract void partidoDeFutbol();
 }
```

despues tengo la SubClase:

```
 public class Entrenador extends Persona{
 //Atributos
 private final String estrategia;

 //Metodos
public Entrenador(String estrategia, String nombre, String apellido, int edad)  {
     super(nombre, apellido, edad);
     this.estrategia = estrategia;
 }

  @Override
  public void viajeDeEquipo(){
    System.out.println("El entrenador prepara sus antoaciones de estrategias 
    y esta listo para viajar.");
  }

 @Override
  public void partidoDeFutbol(){
     System.out.println("El entrenador"
            +apellido+" se sienta en el banquillo y esta listo para 
dirigir.");   
  }

   public void planificarEntrenamiento(){
     System.out.println("El entrenador "
             +nombre+"revisa su estrategia: "+estrategia);
   }
}
```

y en el main hice un arrayList de tipo Persona en el cual almaceno las subclases en cada posicion (hay otras subclases como futbolista o doctor pero no tienen relacion con mi problema):

```
static ArrayList<Persona> p1 = new ArrayList<Persona>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Futbolista f1 = new Futbolista(10,"Mediocampista","Javier","Pastore",28);
    p1.add(f1);
    Entrenador e1 = new Entrenador("Jugar al contraataque", "Marcelo", "Bielsa",62);
    p1.add(e1);
    //el codigo sigue...
```

el problema es que quiero a traves de un menu que se seleccione cierta accion a realizar pero al tratar de acceder al metodo de la subclase 'Entrenador' del arrayList no me reconoce los metodos de dicha clase si no solamente los de la super clase 'Persona'.

```
switch(opcion){
            case 1:
                for (Persona pers : p1) {
                    pers.viajeDeEquipo();
                    System.out.println("");
                }
                System.out.println("");
                break;

            //Siguen los cases...

            //Aca es donde no me reconoce el metodo
            case 4:
                System.out.println(p1.get(1).planificarEntrenamiento());
                break;
        }
```

Se supone que en el arrayList en esta posicion es de tipo Entrenador (incluso lo verifique con el metodo 'getClass()') pero no puedo acceder a este metodo no se que estare haciendo mal...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que `p1` es una lista de `Personas`, por tanto `p1.get(n)` **siempre** devuelve un objeto `Persona`. Incluso lo siguiente te daría error:

```
Persona entrenador= new Entrenador(...); //correcto, un Entrenador es una persona

entrenador.planificarEntrenamiento(); //error de compilación
```

La solución es la siguiente:

```
if (p1.get(1) instanceof Entrenador) {
    Entrenador e = (Entrenador) p1.get(1); //Casting explícito
    e.planificarEntrenamiento();
}
```

Comment: Ahi funciono gracias!!! no sabia si era correcto hacer casting.